# Postgres connectivity via JDBC: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "prescriptions" does not exist

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I'm having a ton of trouble connecting to a dockerized postgres instance. The error I get looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "prescriptions" does not exist
  Position: 29
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:313)
```

Here are the steps to recreate the issue. First, I set up the database like so:

```
docker run -p 7654:5432 --name zoo_postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="stranger" -e POSTGRES_USER=stranger -d postgres
```

And run a setup script, that looks like this:

```
create DATABASE stranger;
create SCHEMA   stranger;

CREATE TABLE prescriptions (
  prescription_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (prescription_id)
);

CREATE USER stranger_user WITH ENCRYPTED password 'stranger_user';

grant CONNECT on DATABASE stranger to stranger_user;
grant USAGE on SCHEMA stranger to stranger_user;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA stranger TO stranger_user;
GRANT INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA stranger TO stranger_user;
GRANT DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA stranger TO stranger_user;
GRANT UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA stranger TO stranger_user;

-- I've tried several variations of the line below, without any effect
ALTER USER stranger_user SET SEARCH_PATH to stranger,stranger_user,public;
```

On the Java side, the code is extremely simple and looks like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:7654/stranger","stranger_user", "stranger_user"); // this succeeds (suggesting the connection string is correct)
    connection.setCatalog("stranger");
    connection.setSchema("stranger");
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("select prescription_id from prescriptions");
    // code dies before getting to the close line.
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("Successfully connected using JDBC directly");
}
```

Setting the catalog and schema has no effect and neither does changing the search path. Everything is lower case, so I don't think it has anything to do with escaping the table names. I've tried using the real user (and skipping the user account), omitting the database name and several other tricks. I suspect that there's something wrong with the way that I'm connecting to the database, but I can connect to is using psql, like so:

```
% psql -h localhost -p 7654 -d postgres -U stranger_user
```

From this point, I can access the tables with normal sql:

```
% psql -h localhost -p 7654 -d postgres -U stranger_user     
Password for user stranger_user: 
psql (9.4.6, server 9.5.2)
WARNING: psql major version 9.4, server major version 9.5.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \d
              List of relations
  Schema  |     Name      | Type  |  Owner   
----------+---------------+-------+----------
 stranger | prescriptions | table | stranger
(1 row)

postgres=> select * from prescriptions;
 prescription_id 
-----------------
(0 rows)

postgres=> select * from stranger.prescriptions;
 prescription_id 
-----------------
(0 rows)
```

I'm using the latest version of the postgres driver: `"org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4+"`, and can't see anything else that would cause this issue. At this point I'm out of ideas and can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Moved my comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pgAdmin or psql, and log in to server `localhost:6543`, database `stranger` with user `stranger_user` and password `stranger_user`, what do you see?

I expect that you see an empty `public` schema.

Running `create DATABASE stranger` does not make it the active database.

So, running `create SCHEMA stranger` will create that schema in the `postgres` database. It *also* won't make the new schema active.

So, running `CREATE TABLE prescriptions` will create that table in the `public` schema of the `postgres` database.

Of course, all that is not even in the PostgreSQL database instance/cluster served on port 6543, because you did all that on a *different* instance/cluster on port 7654.

Comment: The port issue is a red herring and isn't the main cause of the error (an incorrect port causes a different error code). You correctly identified the root cause: it's is that the active database is, in this case, `public` not `stranger`.

Answer (score 2):

You're connecting with `psql` to port 7654, and then in your JDBC URL to port 6543.  Also, you're connecting to the `postgres` database with `psql`, and the `stranger` database in your JDBC URL.

Could these differences be the source of the exception you're seeing?

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html

Comment: Sorry, the port was a typo. You're right that the database exists within the postgres database, not the stranger one.